# How can I access an array of objects from GData JSON in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, json, gdata, jekyll, liquid

I am trying to write a Jekyll extension that will embed comments from a Blogger blog.
I am able to fetch the comments feed as JSON, and process it enough to pull out the total number of comments. However, I have not figured out how to process each comment in the feed.

```rb
json_url = "http://www.blogger.com/feeds/8505008/593465383646513269/comments/default/?alt=json"
json_rep = Net::HTTP.get_response(json_url)
json_rep = JSON.parse(json_rep.body)
json_rep['feed']['openSearch$totalResults']['$t'] # => "4"
json_rep['feed']['entry'].class # => Array

json_rep['feed']['entry'].length
# => Liquid Exception: undefined method `length' for nil:NilClass in post
```

This is my first time writing any code in Ruby. What am I doing wrong?

Here are the relevant parts of the [JSON I am trying to parse](http://www.blogger.com/feeds/8505008/593465383646513269/comments/default/?alt=json).

```js
{
  "feed": {
    "openSearch$totalResults": {
      "$t": "4"
    },
    "entry": [
      {
        "id": {
          "$t": "tag:blogger.com,1999:blog-8505008.post-491866073982779922"
        },
        "published": {
          "$t": "2013-01-08T15:23:47.322-04:00"
        },
        "content": {
          "type": "html",
          "$t": "Recently, my sister has updated it more than I have. \u00dcber-fail on my part. :p"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you should look at doing:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'json'
require 'net/http'
require 'net/https'
require 'uri'

url = "http://www.blogger.com/feeds/8505008/593465383646513269/comments/default/?alt=json"
uri = URI.parse(url)
http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
request = Net::HTTP::Get.new(uri.request_uri)
response = http.request(request)

json_rep = JSON.parse(response.body)

puts json_rep['feed']['openSearch$totalResults']['$t']

entries = json_rep['feed']['entry']
entries.each do |entry|
    puts entry["id"]["$t"]
    #add what ever code you like here
end
```

This outputs:

```
4
tag:blogger.com,1999:blog-8505008.post-491866073982779922
tag:blogger.com,1999:blog-8505008.post-4792479891671746788
tag:blogger.com,1999:blog-8505008.post-4766604955439002209
tag:blogger.com,1999:blog-8505008.post-5484003770204916000
```

Comment: entries.each do |entry| # => Liquid Exception: undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass in post

Comment: `entry` Certainly _is_ a child of `feed`.

Comment: So it is, then it would be the first way. If you're getting a `null` error, that means that there is no data in the `entry` variable.

Comment: Can you post the entire JSON feed? I get the feeling that the path we are talking about isn't correct.

Comment: http://www.blogger.com/feeds/8505008/593465383646513269/comments/default/?alt=json

Comment: `json_rep['feed']['entry'].class` returns `Array`

Comment: what does `json_rep['feed']['entry'].to_s` return?

Comment: `gd$extendedPropertyvaluepid-2088078498nameblogger.itemClassvalueTuesday, January 08, 2013nameblogger.displayTimeauthoruri$thttp://www.blogger.com/profile/00311489051683440057gd$imageheight32src//lh4.googleusercontent.com/-81hGUS5fvI0/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/xGU5tBE3p60/s512-c/photo.jpgrelhttp://schemas.google.com/g/2005#thumbnailwidth32name$tPat Hawksemail$tnoreply@blogger.comupdated$t2013-01-08T15:23:47.322-04:00linkreledittypeapplication/atom+xmlhrefhttp://www.blogger.com/feeds/8505008/593465383646513269/comments/default/491866073982779922relselftypeapplication/atom+xmlhrefhttp://www.bl...`

Comment: See updated answer. That works, I tried it myself. Good luck :)

Comment: `Liquid Exception: undefined method 'each' for nil:NilClass in post`

Comment: I don't know what to tell you man. The code I posted worked with the script I wrote. That means that you are doing something different. If you do EXACTLY what I posted in my answer it will work.

Comment: OH NO. The problem lied in some upstream code. I am so sorry. Yes, your solution works perfectly. Thank you.

Comment: Glad I could help. Good luck with your project.